# How to get the Placeholder of a TMPro.TMP_InputField in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have `TMPro.TMP_InputField`, but I am confused how to get the `Placeholder` of that.

[image]

`.Placeholder` is `null`, so that doesn't point to anything.

Also it seems like `Placeholder` is a subcomponent of an empty game object called `Text Area`?

And from what I see there is no `.GetComponents()` that returns all sub-components, unless you know the type (and I don't know what type `Text Area` is).

[image]

So, I am unsure how to effectively get the `Placeholder` component so that I can manipulate it.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The place holder is not a component. It is a child game object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to target it with:

`inputfield.transform.Find("Text Area").Find("Placeholder").GetComponent<TMPro.TMP_Text>();`